# what is actually dynamic hyperlink column?

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, hyperlink, telerik

hello friends
i am unable to understand the dynamic hyperlink column ?
is it a control present in telerik or an implicit control within telerik radgridiew?

what are the events associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

See my reply here, friend: [difference between dynamic hyperlink column and hyperlink column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909204/difference-between-dynamic-hyperlink-column-and-hyperlink-column/5967376#5967376)

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik Dynamic Hyperlink column is not a control.  It is a Silverlight RadGridView column type. It is designed to be used with business objects that makes it easy to specify very similar (but not exactly the same) URLs for navigation purposes.  The Dynamic Hyperlink column is different from a regular hyperlink column in that a URL does not need to be associated with a business object.