# difference between dynamic hyperlink column and hyperlink column

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, hyperlink, telerik

what is the exact difference between the above mentioned.
also i am not able to understand what is bound field?
i mean i had used it number of times but never exactly understood the same.

please explain me by giving example that what difference it will create if i use one in place of other?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably get the same results with built-in hyperlink grid column and a template column which hosts an asp hyperlink. In case you are talking about the telerik AJAX grid, you can see the available set of columns in it [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/generalfeatures/columntypes/defaultcs.aspx) and read the docs [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-column-types.html).

Comment: Dear Dick i understood Hyperlink column but what is actually benefit of dynamic hyperlink column is still not clear.

Comment: please help in understanding what does word dynamic means in reference to hyperlink column

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The "Dynamic Hyperlink" column is a part of the Telerik Silverlight RadGridView control and is NOT part of Telerik ASP.NET AJAX RadGridView. Also, Template Columns again refer to the asp.net AJAX RadGridView and not the Silverlight RadGridView.  However, the spirit of the answer is correct in that Dynamic Hyperlink Column can be "faked" with a Hyperlink Column.

Answer (score 0):

The Telerik Dynamic Hyperlink is a Silverlight RadGridView column type. It is designed to be used with business objects and makes it easy to specify very similar (but not exactly the same) URLs for navigation purposes. The Dynamic Hyperlink column is different from a regular hyperlink column in that a URL does not need to be associated with a business object.

Comment: i am not able to understand the last line."URL does not need to be associated with a business object".what is business object?

Comment: That is a really REALLY big question.  You should definitely go open a new StackOverflow question for that. Here is a Wikipedia article to get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object but you'll need to spend time learning about Business Objects. The key thing here to note is that if you don't know what a business object is then you can forget about using Dynamic Hyperlink columns.

Comment: I had studied the definition given on the link.Thanks i will study it in more detail.